# Defining URL for new repository location

Tags: svn

I am using Aptana Studio 2.0.2 with PDT plugin on Ubuntu Linux platform. I want to create a new repository, and for that I selected: "New Repository Location" in SVN Perspective.

It asks for the URL of the new location. In what format I need to define the path of the repository on my local machine?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new repository, or check out from an existing repository?

Comment: I now created new repository from command line and now I want to add a new repository location and import the repository data from one of my mounted Windows volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit of digging around, Aptana seems to be based on Eclipse, and you're probably using Subversive or Subclipse for the SVN perspective.  These plugins make it easy to check out an existing repository, but aren't designed to create new repositories.

If you're looking to create a new repository, you should probably do that outside of the IDE using [svnadmin](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re29.html).

Edit: If you have an already exiting repository on your local machine and are looking add it, try the `file:///path/to/repository` format.  [See here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s07.html).